# erro mysql Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysqli

pessoal estou com um problema em um update. 
da este erro

> **string(42) " UPDATE files SET desc='ssss' WHERE id=131" Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'desc='ssss' WHERE id=131' at line 1**

segue meu código

```
 <?php
// Include the database configuration file
require 'conn/conn1.php';

$id_img = $_POST['id'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];

$sql = " UPDATE files SET desc='$desc' WHERE id=$id_img";
var_dump($sql);

   if (mysqli_query($conn1, $sql)) {
      echo "Record updated successfully";
   } else {
      echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn1);
   }
   mysqli_close($conn1);
?>
```

poderiam me ajudar por favor!

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, aparentemente não há concatenação entre sua string sql e sua variavel '.$variavel.', também se caso essa variavel for receber alguma string utilize '".$variavel."' espero ter ajudado.